# Where is dynamic_sidebar content defined?

Tags: sidebar

A friend has asked me to edit a WordPress site that someone else has made for them.  Part of it contains the following code:

```
dynamic_sidebar('footer4')
```

Which spews out a contact form.

What I want to know is, is there an easy way for me to find out where the function that returns the HTML this contact form is defined?

For example, if there was actually a function called 'footer4', I could do this:

```
// I've tried this and it doesn't exist;)
$reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction('footer4');
print $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine();
```

I've looked through all the template files and couldn't see anything.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more clear and let us know, what is the issue you are facing? and about `dynamic_sidebar` you can find the details about it in the [`Codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

Comment: Hope that clears it up a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check **Apperances>Widgets** Under **footer4** inside text you can find the HTML form you need to edit. You can find more in [Function Reference/dynamic sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)